# Prevent destruction of object passed by interface

Tags: delphi, interface

i don't have much experience with interfaces in Delphi and Delphi at all.

Example:

```
IListModel = interface
    function At(row, col : Integer) : String;
end;

MyModel = class(TInterfacedObject, IListModel)
public
    function At(row, col : Integer) : String;
    procedure ManipulateA;
    procedure ManipulateBogus;
end;
```

There is a view that can visualize objects that implement the IListModel interface.

```
View = class(TForm)
public
    constructor Create(model : IListModel); reintroduce;
end;
```

My app holds a MyModel instance

```
MyApp = class({...})
strict private
    model : MyModel;
public
 // ...
end;
```

In the app i create the model and work with it.

```
procedure MyApp.LoadModel;
procedure MyApp.OnFoo;
begin
    model.ManipulateBogus;
end;
```

Now, i want to show the data

```
procedure MyApp.ShowModel;
var
    v : View;
begin
    v := View.Create(model); // implicit to IListView > refCount=1
    v.ShowModal;
    FreeAndNil(v);
    // refCount = 0
    // oops, my model is dead now
end;
```

I'm wondering what's the best way to solve this problem.
In MyApp i could hold both, the instance model : MyModel AND via IListModel interface.
Or I could introduce a new interface IMyModel and hold the model by this interface in the MyApp class. I had to use if Supports(...) in the ShowModel method to get the IListModel interface.
Or i derive the MyModel class from another non refcounting base class (TInterfacedPersistent or a self written class). Any other ideas?

What is the best way to work with interfaces in such situations?

Edit:
A non ref counting base class:

```
function NonRefCountingObject.QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID;
                                             out Obj): HResult;
begin
  if GetInterface(IID, Obj) then
    Result := S_OK
  else
    Result := E_NOINTERFACE;
end;

function NonRefCountingObject._AddRef: Integer;
begin
    Result := -1;  // no reference counting
end;

function NonRefCountingObject._Release: Integer;
begin
    Result := -1;  // no reference counting
end;
```

Is this implementation ok?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use the reference counting that comes with interfaces, you should only reference that object through interfaces. No references to the object other than through interfaces and do not free the object yourself.

Or you could disable the reference counting by overriding _AddRef and _Release and destroy the object like you are used to. This is what TComponent does.

Or keep the reference counting, but call AddRef and Release when you reference it like an object.

**edit**

using a const parameter prevents reference count updating and speeds up your code:

```
constructor Create(const model : IListModel); reintroduce;
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Is it safe to replace TInterfacedObject or TComponent base class with the NonRefCountingObject class from my edit? Is this implementation correct?

Comment: @hansmaad: What Lars means in his first sentence, is that you should replace `model : MyModel` in `MyApp` with with `model : IListModel`. That makes sure that `MyApp` keeps a reference (until `MyApp` dies; then the refcount of `model` is decreased, when that refcount becomes zero, it is being automagically freed).

Comment: @Jeroen: You're right. But the IListModel doesn't declare the ManipulateBogus prodecure because it's MyModel specific stuff. MyApp is owner of the Model, it creates the model, manipulates the model and delegates the visualization to a view. The view has no knowledge about the concrete type of the model it shows. If i stored `model : IListModel` in MyApp, the app instance wouldn't have access to ManipulateBogus. I think i had to introduce another IMyModel interface and use this one in MyApp.

Comment: If your interface doesn't support what you are trying to do, then either you are trying to do something you shouldn't have to do, or your interface is wrong.

Comment: @Nick: There is more than 'the interface'. MyModel implements the IListModel interface because it can be shown in a list view. There are a lot of models that can be shown in a list view. And each of them has its own specific additional methods. I could derive from a real ListModel base class and everything works fine, as long as i don't want to derive from an additional base class, because there is no multiple inheritance in Delphi. For the moment i like the idea of the non ref counting base class.

Comment: @Lars (edit: using a const parameter): I played a little bit with const arguments and ffind out that it can be very confusing and dangerous. My example works well with `const model : IListModel` but if i add a view which shows a temporary model, the ref counter stays at 1. `View.Create(AnotherModel.Create);`. I don't like such a design of big surprise, but good to know about this behaviour. Thx for this advice.

Comment: @hansmaad: indeed; hide `MyModel` in the implementation section, and have it implement another `IMyModel` interface that exposes the `ManipulateBogus` procedure. Then you have the benefit of one kind of memory management, and accessibility of all the features you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you need both, Interfaces and object references, simply derive from TInterfacedPersistent (declared in Classes.pas) instead of TInterfacedObject. Be aware that you must assure that no interface reference is still hold when you free the instance.

Comment: Is there a good introductory write-up available anywhere on TInterfacedObject, TInterfacedPersistent, and similar object/interface hybrids?